# UITableView only updating on scroll up, not down

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a UITableView that updates when I scroll up, but it does not update when I scroll down. Furthermore, when it does update it occasionally seems to "skip" a cell and update the next one.

1. There are 6 total cells that should populate
2. I've created the UITableView in the storyboard, set my constraints for both the hashLabel and the creditLabel in storyboard

Here is the image of the initial TableView:

[image: initial TableView load]

And upon scrolling up, when updated properly:

[image]

...and when scrolling up "misses" a cell:

[image]

and of course, the class:

```
class HashtagController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource  {

  var model:ModelData!
  var currentCell: UITableViewCell!
  @IBOutlet var hashtagTableView: UITableView!
  let basicCellIdentifier = "CustomCells"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    model = (self.tabBarController as CaptionTabBarController).model
    hashtagTableView.delegate = self
    hashtagTableView.dataSource = self
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CherrySwash-Regular", size: 25)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red:27.0/255, green: 145.0/255, blue: 114.0/255, alpha: 1.0)]
    configureTableView()
    hashtagTableView.reloadData()
  }

  func configureTableView() {
    hashtagTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    hashtagTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //deselectAllRows()
    hashtagTableView.reloadData()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    hashtagTableView.reloadData()
  }

  func deselectAllRows() {
    if let selectedRows = hashtagTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {
      for indexPath in selectedRows {
        hashtagTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
      }
    }
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return model.quoteItems.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return customCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
  }

  func customCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CustomCells {
    var cell = hashtagTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier) as CustomCells
    setTitleForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    setSubtitleForCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
  }

  func setTitleForCell(cell:CustomCells, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
    let item = Array(Array(model.quoteItems.values)[indexPath.row])[0] as? String
    cell.hashLabel.text = item
  }

  func setSubtitleForCell(cell:CustomCells, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
    let item = Array(model.quoteItems.keys)[indexPath.row]
    cell.creditLabel.text = item
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    /*currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    var currentLabel = currentCell.textLabel?.text
    var currentAuthor = currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text

    model.quote = currentLabel!
    model.author = currentAuthor!*/
  }
}

class CustomCells: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var hashLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var creditLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: What is `ModelData.quoteItems` ? Is it an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: I'm also wondering if `item` in both `-setTitleForCell` and `-setSubTitleForCell` are `nil` in the empty rows. If so, why?

Comment: I've done a println and all data seems to be printed, no errors show up.

Comment: You should convert your dictionary to an array of `Quote`  objects once (or at least put all of the keys in array once) and  then access the data directly from that array.

Comment: I agree with Paul, the `NSDictionary` is not what you want if you care about the order of the items. It could also be the source of your problem.

Comment: I ended up using tuples for the data. This worked much more elegantly, especially when accessing them. Thanks a lot for the suggestion guys. This didn't fix the problem though, it was as a result of my 'estimatedRowHeight' being too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue had to do with my `estimatedRowHeight`. In this case the row height was too large and it was effecting the way the table cells were being constructed.

So in the end I changed `hashtagTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0` to `hashtagTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0` and everything worked just fine.